# Generate PDF report from php

Tags: php, pdf

I am using php code to query to a database and the results will be used to generate a report.

If I want the report to be generated in a pdf format how should I do it ?

Comment: how about using latex???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need UTF support in your PDF file, consider `tcpdf` library.

Download it from here: http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf

And in your script:

```
<?php
//include files
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 

//add some content using class methods

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look into [html2pdf](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm)

Create your report as html and then run the code to transform into PDF. You don't need to know the language to generate the PDF blocks. Submitted forms work out cool too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), I've used that for several projects. In the beginning you will be annoyed a lot, but when you get used to it, it will get easier to create pdf's :)

Comment: this is really fine... but its little difficult when the requirement is complected

Answer (score 1):

I've used TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org/) for my last project. It worked pretty good but the next time im going for a html to pdf converter, simply because designing the report (converting to pdf draw statements) was such a time sink.

So i would suggest http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/