# Php reporting - best way to make a PDF

Tags: php, pdf, reporting

I think that reporting in PHP is very hard. I tried the raw methods of FPdf or R&OS but i would like to know if there is something more friendly to use like JasperReport or Adobe LiveCycle.
I saw somewhere the php javabridge to run jasperreport from php, but i don't like very much this solution.

What do you use for php reporting? Don't you think that fPdf or smiliar are not very friendly for standard reports?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417315/generate-pdf-report-from-php

Comment: Exactly what report are you trying to generate to PDF? Error reoprts? Logs? Client reports? Reports for the users to download? What?

Comment: fpdf has been very friendly for me. Whats your problem?

Comment: This is just an idea. You can create HTML report and then convert HTML files to PDF. For HTML to PDF you can use either http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ or http://www.convertapi.com

Comment: For reporting I mean PDF for print (please see title)

Comment: I know that fPdf has simple methods, but i would like to create a report template with some gui application... HTML to PDF can be very nice but can I manage page breaks, headers and footers?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for creating Excel files and [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) for PDF. Both are very well written object oriented libraries and don't need any external extensions.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by php reporting?

For generating PDF files I use and highly recommend [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/), which does not require any special extensions on the server.