# Is it posible to generate a word or pdf file in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate PDF report from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417315/generate-pdf-report-from-php)

Is it possible to generate a word or pdf document using php? I am making a web page that generates report ( an evaluation sheet to be exact that contains the rating per staff) and I'm wondering if it is possible to generate such documents.

Comment: Sure, why shouldn't it not be possible to generate any kind of output? I mean PHP is a programming language. You can even generate a doc file *and* a pdf file in php. So two times yes as the answer to your question. What do you need to know more?

Comment: Would also like to know a good detailed and useful answer to this. Good question. It must be possible, but would love to know in detail

Comment: There are a lot of resources on how to do this. You should do some searching first before posting a new question.

Comment: @Ryan Murphy: Just search this site and the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either use some PDF generation library designed to work with PHP (maybe http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php ?).  IMO, these libraries can be tricky to use because you have to learn their own markup syntax.

You could also use an  html -> pdf generator such as wkhtmltopdf or Princexml -- these are external commands that you would need to call after generating html/css with php.  These are easier to use because the syntax is (presumably) familiar, but the styling can be trickier for things like cover pages, headers, footers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) for generating .docx files via PHP

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making your document in HTML and styling it as you like it.  Then use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert it to a pdf.  Then you can execute this command from PHP like this:

```
shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf /path/to/document/document.html /path/to/document/document.pdf');
```