# print report generated by php code

Tags: php, printing, report, generated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate PDF report from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417315/generate-pdf-report-from-php)

I am building a database app for a client in PHP/mySQL. There are several dynamic reports that are generated. The client would like his staff to be able to print these reports. He does not want the header/footer to print out and apparently, it is too much of a pain to teach all of his staff how to turn that off before printing. He saw another website that generated PDFs when things needed to be printed and he likes that.

Comment: Why not use print css to hide the headers ? Or do you want a PDF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to hide objects while printing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page) and FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) to create PDF-Documents.